# How to add picture into Word Header which contains already a table?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to add a picture (company logo) into a header by code. 
This worked fine so far until there showed up some documents which contain a table in the header, which I want to keep there too.

Problem is: my code adds the picture into the first table cell. What i want is that the picture is positioned in the top right corner of the page (with some margin to the page) .. but outside the table.

How do I need to modify my code to do that? I guess the problem is the Range I use:

```
    Set oSec = ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
    Set oHeader = oSec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
    Set Rng = oHeader.Range '<<-- Problem here? What to do if there is a table in the header
    Set sh = ActiveDocument.shapes.AddPicture(LogoFile, False, True, 0, 0, , , Rng)
    With sh
        .Height = LogoDimension
        .Width = LogoDimension
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTopBottom
        .WrapFormat.Side = wdWrapTopBottom
        .WrapFormat.DistanceBottom = MillimetersToPoints(10)
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionRightMarginArea
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
        .Left = MillimetersToPoints(0.5) - LogoDimension
        .Top = MillimetersToPoints(11.5)
    End With
```

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: If your picture has an absolute position on the page it should not be a problem that it is anchored to the first table cell. Is there an issue with the position?

Comment: actually its not absolute .. I said that wrongly. the position is set relative to the top right corner .. at least it should be. If there is no table its working fine. But if there is a table the picture is put inside the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to test the scenario on my dev machine and could reproduce the problem. Shape management in Word's Headers/Footers is notorious for being "pliable" - this appears to be another one of those things.

What works is to insert the graphic in the paragraph below the table as an `InlineShape` object, use the `ConvertToShape` method, then immediately lock the anchor of the Shape so that moving it doesn't shift the anchor position to the nearest paragraph (table cell).

```
Sub InsertPicInHeaderOutsideTable()
    Dim oSec As word.Section
    Dim oHeader As word.HeaderFooter
    Dim rng As word.Range
    Dim sh As word.Shape, ils As word.InlineShape

    Set oSec = ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
    Set oHeader = oSec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
    Set rng = oHeader.Range 
    '**** Add the followign four lines to code in your question ****
    rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Set ils = rng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(LogoFile, False, True, rng)
    Set sh = ils.ConvertToShape
    sh.LockAnchor = True
    With sh
       'and so on...
```

Comment: wow, sounds great! thanks a lot already! 

I will try this tomorrow and report back then and mark the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

after some more playing around with it I found the solution:

```
                    .LayoutInCell = False
```

adding this attribute to the shape will lead to positioning the picture as wanted and not affect the table anymore.

edit: this was not entirely correct it seems. The picture is still added to the table .. just not positioned in the cell anymore. If I delete the table for testing the picture gets deleted automatically with it. So this is not an ideal solution still. 
I think still the range used is the problem

Comment: I agree with your assessment. Try adding Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd before AddPicture. I suspect you may also need to set the WrapFormat to "Behind" or "in front of" the text, so that it doesn't interfere with the table (push it down).

Comment: thanks for the hints .. I tried both ways now, but the picture is still added to the table instead of below it.

If I delete the table the picture will be gone aswell. 

I tried also to use a selection:
                     oHeader.Range.Select
                    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                     Set sh = ActiveDocument.shapes.AddPicture(CovLogoFile, False, True, 0, 0, , , Selection.Range)

same behavior here .. interesting if i type text it ends below the table.. the picture still inside the table tho.